# File type icon in a visual studio tab?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to view file type icons in a visual studio tab?  It displays them in the little drop down menu (upper right arrow of an editor), but not in the tabs.  Is this a feature?

Personally I would hide the extension and show the icon.

Comment: Duplicated with [this post][1] about Visual Studio 2012.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163922/show-file-type-icons-on-tabs-on-visual-studio-2012

Comment: My question is 4 years older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this possible with the normal install but there is a tabs groups add-on called Tabs Studio which provides extra functionality.

Comment: I'm going to mark this is as correct, as I think you're right!