# Show file type icons on tabs on visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tabs

I wass looking for quite some time now how I could see the file type icon of each file I have opened in visual studio 2012 tab well, like it was shown on previous versions of visual studio. This was completely removed from vs 12, couldn't find any option enabling this. This is something extemely usefull when having many open files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that this option exists on the registry!
So you go here:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.CustomDocWell.Options

and change the **IconInTabs** property from false to True!

File type icons are displayed again next to each tab!!!!

Edit: In order for this to work you must have installed Productivity Power Tools 2012 plugin

Comment: Not work for me!in `visual studio ultimate 2012, Version 11.0.61.30 Update 4`. any Idea?

Comment: Do you have Productivity Power Tools 2012 plugin installed? This might be needed although I cannot confirm that because I already had them.

Comment: yes! the problem was I hadn't `Productivity Power Tools`, installed it and Icons appeared. Please mention the requirement of the tool in your answer. thanks.

Comment: Not work to me. I've `visual studio ultimate 2013 update 4` with PPTools installed. How to make it ?

Comment: @Yang C, unfortunately I haven't figured out how to make it work for vs 2013 it works only in vs 2012 as I say in the title.